# Query regarding Python Multiple Regex Expression

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Python, just trying to solve a few regex expressions, I was stuck with the below code. Kindly help me out on this.

```py
import re
a = ["my mac is aa-bb-cc-33-44-SS","Hostname: xyz1"]
for i in a:
    c = re.findall(r"\\D{2}-\\D{2}-\\D{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\D{2}|:(.\*)",i)
    print(c)
```

Output for above code is :
['']
[' xyz1']

But the output really needed is
['aa-bb-cc-33-44-SS']
['xyz1]

Comment: What are the other possible inputs?

Answer (score 0):

I can spot two mistakes in the code.

1. if you use raw string you don't have to escape `/` or `*`
   so it would just be
   `re.findall(r"\D{2}-\D{2}-\D{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\D{2}|:(.*)", i)`
2. you don't group the first expression:
   `re.findall(r"(\D{2}-\D{2}-\D{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\D{2})|:(.*)", i)`

```
>> a = ["my mac is aa-bb-cc-33-44-SS","Hostname: xyz1"]
>> for i in a:
>>     c = re.findall(r"(\D{2}-\D{2}-\D{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\D{2})|:(.*)", i)
>>     print(c)

[('aa-bb-cc-33-44-SS', '')]
[('', ' xyz1')]
```

Comment: import re
a = ("my mac is aa-bb-cc-33-44-SS")
c = re.findall(r"\D{2}\-\D{2}\-\D{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\D{2}",a)
print(c)  .. This works when adding(\) inside raw string. but when using | it is not working as expected

Comment: may I know the specific error you give when u run my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?:[^\d\s-]{2}-){3}\d{2}-\d{2}-[^\d\s-]{2}|(?<=:\s).+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uza6ng/2). *Details*:

- `(?:[^\d\s-]{2}-){3}` - three occurrences of two chars other than digits, whitespaces and hyphens followed with `-`
- `\d{2}-\d{2}-` - two sequences of two digits and a `-` char
- `[^\d\s-]{2}` - two chars other than digits, whitespaces and hyphens followed with `-`
- `|` - or
- `(?<=:\s).+` - any one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible (`.+`) that are immediately preceded with a colon and a whitespace.

In Python, use

```py
re.findall(r'(?:[^\d\s-]{2}-){3}\d{2}-\d{2}-[^\d\s-]{2}|(?<=:\s).+', i)
```